# Is it possible to scan all controls in a specific UpdatePanel and determine if they're visible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, updatepanel

I'm aware of this question which already exists:

[How to use for loop to scan all controls in page in ASP .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658283/how-to-use-for-loop-to-scan-all-controls-in-page-in-asp-net)

However, I don't want to scan the whole page.  I have 4 UpdatePanels on my page, and I only want to check the controls which reside in a specific UpdatePanel.  I want to check only the textboxes and dropdownlists to see if they're visible, and then dynamically set their tab indexes.

Can this be done?

Comment: Use the extension method from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5658374/864696) and apply the `All()` method to your `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Is your UpdatePanel named? Can't you go through the `Controls` property to find what you need?

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707107/looping-through-children-controls-inside-updatepanel